# convert XML to a custom Excel with Java

Tags: java, excel, xml-parsing, apache-poi

I need advise about how to convert XML to a custom Excel with Java
I need to convert XML to Excel with a custom layout. I found a [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and it seems like it can help with this task. But I don't have this experiences and as I understood POI works the best with in memory trees like DOM. I started to pars my XML(I can show a small part of, it's really big and goes deep)

```
<advantage>
    <companies>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <name>Name2</name>
        <name>Name3</name>
        <name>Name4</name>
        <name>Name6</name>
    </companies>
    <companyPreCode>
        <PreCode>1</PreCode>
        <PreCode>2</PreCode>
        <PreCode>3</PreCode>
        <PreCode>4</PreCode>
        <PreCode>6</PreCode>
    </companyPreCode>
```

by using DOM as I saw in one online tutorial like this

```
        Document xmlDoc = getDocument("./src/xmlForTest.xml");
        xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element of the doc is :\" "+ xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "\"");

        NodeList listOfAdvantage = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("advantage"); //first we need to find total number of Advantage blocks
        int totalAdvantage = listOfAdvantage.getLength();

        System.out.println("Total no of advantage : " + totalAdvantage);
        for (int s = 0; s < listOfAdvantage.getLength(); s++) //get into advantage
        {
            Node AdvantageNode = listOfAdvantage.item(s);
            System.out.println("advantage number : " + s);
            if (AdvantageNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element AdvantageElement = (Element) AdvantageNode;
                NodeList CompanyList = AdvantageElement.getElementsByTagName("companies"); // find node companies
                System.out.println("companies number : " + CompanyList.getLength());
                for(int cl = 0; cl < CompanyList.getLength(); cl++) {
                    NodeList CompanyNameList = CompanyList.item(cl).getChildNodes();  //AdvantageElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
                    for (int j = 0; j < CompanyNameList.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node childNode = CompanyNameList.item(j);
                        if ("name".equals(childNode.getNodeName())) {
                            for (int nl = 0; nl < CompanyNameList.getLength(); nl++) {
                                Element CompanyNameElement = (Element) CompanyNameList.item(nl);
                                NodeList textFNList = CompanyNameElement.getChildNodes();
                                System.out.println("Company: " + nl + " :" + (textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                                CompaniesNames.add((textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }// end of if clause

        }// end of for loop with s var
```

and now I have several questions

1. How to make this parsing easier? my file is big and in some places I Have the same tags for different things, like Name can be for company, product or a person. But it's getting hard to retrieve it one by one the way I did it
2. How to feed this data later into POI so I can start using this POI to build my Excel files? Because right now I have a set of ArrayLists with my data from different tags and I just don't know what I need to next with it

Comment: So your question to us is: How to convert a XML, of which we don't know the exact structure, into an Excel file of which we also don't know how the structure shall look like? The only thing I can tell you: First determine the exact structure of the XML and the exact structure of the needed Excel sheet. For ex.: Your XML has different companies. Shall each company be one row in the Excel sheet? And if so how shall the other datas be assigned to the company rows? Then your program will read the XML using a parser and write the Excel sheet using POI.

Comment: And btw.: "POI works the best with in memory trees like DOM": No, [apache poi for Excel](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells) needs to write rows containing cells in which the data appears. So the structure of an Excel sheet and also POI is more like a database table having rows of data records and cells into this rows like data fields within the data records.